# How to build a system for an editorial team

Tags: django, content-management-system

I'm developing a web portal that mostly works like a newspaper site. In the focus, there are articles, containing text, videos and images. These articles have attachments which shall be presented in a sidebar. These attachments might be the same objects that will be displayed within the body text.
I have been thinking a lot about how to create the structure and - and this is a major point - how to enable the editor to edit all this stuff comfortably.

What I evaluated were Django-CMS and feincms as complete systems, and several third-party-modules that do snippets of the work.

Now, I a have solution for inline objects: I forked the inline-module of [django-basic-apps](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps) which is now able to take additional parameters for the objects to embed. Their parameters are an important thing to e.g. embed "an image with object id x, but max x pixels in size".

What is not solved with my approach is, to generate a sidebar containing a bunch of inline tokens. I could create a custom widget for this, though. A better solution would surely be to add a functionaly like somehow attaching generic objects (videos, images...) to an article object.

While my solution is working so far, I'm not sure if there are other ways to solve these common scenario, and I would like to hear some other experiences about this topic, and if there are any other ways you deal with it.

---

For there does not seem to be a bigger need of a solution for this generic problem, I will use my solution and see whether it proves in practice.

Comment: why not simply use wordpress out of the box?

Comment: because I have a lot of individual features which need a full-grown, powerful framework like django

Comment: If you'd use django-cms its plugin system (http://www.django-cms.org/en/documentation/2.0/plugins/) would be a powerful alternative to django-inlines and can be administrated by the end user!

Comment: The problem is, that I don't need all the CMS stuff of django-cms, since the site-structure is designed another way. Maybe I could use the plugin-system. Is it possible to use it without taking all the other parts of the cms?

Comment: Have you considered simply rolling your own system ? (And perhaps even open sourcing it?)

The other — possibly impractical — option is to train the users about HTML or whatever markup language being used.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Armstrong CMS](http://armstrongcms.org/). It's specifically designed to meet the needs of news organizations. It was developed out of the code that powers The Texas Tribune, a very large Django news site that won the Edward R. Murrow Award for best local news website in 2010.

Armstrong scales very well, is fast and can handle just about any kind of content you want to throw at it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint; I had a look: The Github-Link on the project page is broken - I found it then later, but I did not see any documentation. Is there any section Im' missing?

Comment: I'm not sure on the documentation. I was the original lead developer of The Tribune, and handed off the reigns to the guys who developed Armstrong. You might get in touch with: http://www.travisswicegood.com/